# Is there any dynamic image technology like a gif to demonstrate new feature in cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

I add some new feature in my app. And I want to introduce it to the users as they use the feature for the first time.

Maybe it needs some complex operations like clicking this button and then clicking that menu item.

So I wonder if there is something or tech acting like a gif to demonstrate the process of the new feature or something like that?

Thank you for your help.